# CSS attribute that simply hides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm sure that there's a really simple solution to this that will make me feel really stupid when I see it. I'm building a little table, with some icons, and (using jQuery) when you roll over the icons a popup div below them tells you the name of it, by fading in and then fading out when you roll out. the problem is, the way I built it, the items are arranged in a table, and then most of the styling comes from a class applied to each of them. To hide the table, so that it's elements can fade in, I'm the using        `display: none`
attribute. Everything works fine for the far left icon, yet the problem is the items are in a table, not individually arranged (they can be, which would fix the problem, I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it like this) so on icons in the middle for example, hovering over one will cause the correct bubble to show, yet all the way to the left since the rest of the bubbles in the table are not present (`display:none`). is there a tag or method that will make it so that the table will not be visible, yet still present in form?
This was probably a really confusing way to ask, so I commend you if you understood my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understood you fully, but try this:

```
visibility: hidden
```

It would be great to see some code, so I can help you more.

Comment: yeah i tried that, but it doesn't work with jquery's fadeIn feature, so i was looking for something else. Thanks to all with the same answer! Ill just split it up

Comment: yes, fades only work with display attributes... however, if you really need to use it, you can make the element hidden, then on mouse over make it display: none and visibility: visible, and then do the fade in. that way you'll have it in the hidden state by default and the fade in will work.

Comment: yeah that would have worken, but i just broke up the individual table, nothing to major

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will simply prevent you from seeing the element.  In other words, the element always remains in the normal content flow, taking up space, despite being invisible.

```
visibility: hidden;
```

and to make it reappear...

```
visibility: visible;
```

---

The following will hide the element by removing it.  In other words, the element will be removed from the content flow entirely and the surrounding content will reposition itself to fill the void.

```
display: none;
```

and to make it reappear...

```
display: block;
```